# Can twitter de-activate a government official's account?

Tags: united-states, social-media

I'm curious about this. Twitter's views are more progressive so what do the terms and conditions of twitter say about banning/De-activating a government officials account e.g. Trump's account. I'm sure there would a huge backlash from his supporters and himself.

Comment: This question belongs on Law.SE, not Politics.

Comment: Asking others to read and interpret Twitter's ToS for you seems kinda lazy...

Comment: What's the point of this question? Can they? Yes, they are a private company and can do whatever the eff they want. Then they will probably face backlash (populist one in best case scenario. or if Trump decides abuse IRS for political purposes the way Obama did, there are worse scenarios for Twitter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Twitter is a private company, with promulgated [terms of service](https://twitter.com/tos?lang=en). While the First amendment of the Constitution protects the individuals freedom of speech from being violated by the Government, there is nothing legally constraining Twitter from ending his account.

However, observer the impact of Twitter banning [Milo](https://www.google.com/search?q=twitter%20bans%20milo&oq=twitter%20bans%20milo&aqs=chrome..69i57.3019j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and the increased presence it gave him elsewhere. Of course, this was before is other questionable statements destroyed the prestige.

If twitter banned or ended Trumps account, it would be a strong self inflicted wound.

Comment: One important distinction I would make - the fact that the constitution only applies to the government is not what makes Twitter free to end any account. Its that Twitter's terms of service specify they may suspend any account for any reason. If they did not specify this and suspended an account for an invalid reason (ie one not defined in their contract) they may be sued for contract violations.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg That was the intention with the first paragraph; I'll clear up when time allows.

Comment: "If twitter banned or ended Trumps account, it would be a strong self inflicted wound." = purely in your opinion. It's just as plausible that Twitter would be hailed for it.

Comment: @blip - anyone who would hail it already uses twitter, so what exactly is the practical upside for them?

Comment: @user4012 I don't think there is any upside for Twitter these days. They are a company without a purpose. But that's a whole other topic... :)

Comment: What is Milo doing these days???

Comment: @DavidsaysReinstateMonica is there a contract formed when one makes a Twitter account?

Comment: I guess Twitter is now dying because it banned Trump. Nothing to do with electric neural underground rocket car AI payments, no siree bob.